# How can I get the time zone of a US ZIP code?

Tags: entity

There does not seem to be a direct way to extract the time zone for a ZIP code. Currently, I am first mapping the ZIP code to the states, and then getting the time zones for those states.

```
"94402" //
Entity["ZIPCode", #] & //
EntityValue[#, "USStates"] & //
Map[EntityValue[#, "TimeZones"] &]
```

But this is obviously wrong. This will return multiple time zones even when a given ZIP code lies within a single time zone.

Is there a better way of getting the time zone for a ZIP code through `Entity`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
TimeZoneOffset[Entity["ZIPCode", "94402"]]
```

> -8.

Comment: Ah, didn't occur to me that I don't need to wrap the entity in GeoPosition. Ah well. Graceful method :)

Comment: Thank you @CarlLange.

Answer (score 6):

This will do what you want:

```
TimeZoneOffset[GeoPosition[Entity["ZIPCode", "94402"]["Coordinates"]]]
```

> -8

Each zip code entity has coordinates associated with them, and `TimeZoneOffset` can take a GeoPosition and return the timezone offset from GMT.

It should be noted that kglr's answer is the shorter (and more graceful) form of this answer - they are doing the same thing under the hood.